# Initializing Static Inner Classes

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

Working with a vendor API, I need to set some parameters on an inner class but I am getting the exception:
***Illegal enclosing instance specification for type OuterClass.InnerClass***
on "**oc.new InnerClass()**"

```
OuterClass oc = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass rc2 = oc.new InnerClass();
```

After reading on inner classes, specifically static inner classes, I can instantiate it using:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass myInnerClass = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
myInnerClass.setName("John");
```

My question is, How do I achieve

`MyParentClass parentClass = new MyParentClass();
parentClass.setOuterClassObject(outerClassObject)` 
when I have never instantiated OuterClass object.

Basically I want to set a populated outerClass (with innerClass variables) on MyParentClass.

Comment: Static inner classes *don't have* any outer class object. That's what is meant by static. I don't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the InnerClass is OuterClass. So you can access it just inside the methods of OuterClass. In this case just create the instance of the class as from any other classes.

```
public class OuterClass
{
  class InnerClass
  {
    public InnerClass() { super(); };
    public bar() {};
  }

  private void foo()
  {
    InnerClass aic = new InnerClass();
    aic.bar();
  } 

}
```

A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class. As a member of the OuterClass, a nested class can be declared private, public, protected, or package private. (Recall that outer classes can only be declared public or package private.)

```
public class OuterClass
{
  private class NonStaticInnerClass
  {
    public bar() { foo(); };
  }

  private static class StaticInnerClass
  {
    public bar() { foo(); }; // Compiler error!!!
  }

  private void foo() {} ;
}
```

There is no way to access InnerClass outside of OuterClass (it is undefined) but you can access it as an interface:

```
public interface IInterface
{
  public void bar();
}

public class OuterClass
{
  class InnerClass implemets IInterface
  {
    public InnerClass() { super(); };
    public void bar();
  }

  private InnerClass ic;

  public IInterface getIInterface() { return ic; };
}

public class AnotherClass
{
  private OuterClass oc;

  public foo()
  {
    IInterface iI = oc.getIInterface();
    iI.bar();
  }
}
```